# Watermark trigger in Onyx does not fire

Tags: clojure, windowing, onyx-platform

I have an Onyx stream of segments that are messages with a timestamp (coming in in chronological order). Say, they look like this:

```
{:id 1 :timestamp "2018-09-04 13:15:42" :msg "Hello, World!"}
{:id 2 :timestamp "2018-09-04 21:32:03" :msg "Lorem ipsum"}
{:id 3 :timestamp "2018-09-05 03:01:52" :msg "Dolor sit amet"}
{:id 4 :timestamp "2018-09-05 09:28:16" :msg "Consetetur sadipscing"}
{:id 5 :timestamp "2018-09-05 12:45:33" :msg "Elitr sed diam"}
{:id 6 :timestamp "2018-09-06 08:14:29" :msg "Nonumy eirmod"}
...
```

For each time window (of one day) in the data, I want to run a computation on the set of all its segments. I.e., in the example, I would want to operate on the segments with ids 1 and 2 (for Sept 4th), next on the ids 3, 4 and 5 (for Sept 5th), and so on.

Onyx offers windows and triggers, and they *should* do what I want out of the box. If I use a window of `:window/type :fixed` and aggregate over `:window/range [1 :day]` with respect to `:window/window-key :timestamp`, I will aggregate all segments of each day.

To only trigger my computations when all segments of a day have arrived, Onyx offers the trigger behaviour `:onyx.triggers/watermark`. According to [the documentation](http://www.onyxplatform.org/docs/user-guide/0.13.x/#_watermark), it should fire

> if the value of `:window/window-key` in the segment exceeds the upper-bound in the extent of an active window

**However, the trigger does not fire**, even though I can see that later segments are already coming in and several windows should be full. As a sanity check, I tried a simple `:onyx.triggers/segment` trigger, which worked as expected.

---

My failed attempt at creating a minimal example:

I modified the [fixed windows](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-examples/tree/master/fixed-windows) **toy job** to test watermark triggering, and **it worked there**.

However, [I found out](https://gitter.im/onyx-platform/onyx?at=5b9f5271e5c2cc56ad9f2ca7) that in this toy job, the reason the watermark trigger is firing might be:

> Did it close the input channel? Maybe the job just completed which can trigger the watermark too.

---

Another aspect that interacts with watermark triggering is the distributed work on tasks by **peers**.

The comments to [issue #839](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx/issues/839) (*`:trigger/emit` not working with `:onyx.triggers/watermark`*) in the Onyx repo pointed me to [issue #840](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx/issues/840) (*Watermark doesn't work with Kafka topic having > 1 partition*), where I found this [clue](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx/issues/840#issuecomment-359279697) (emphasis mine):

> The problem is that all of your data is ending up on one partition, and the watermarks **always takes the minimum watermark over all** of the input **peers** (and if using the native kafka watermarks, the minimum watermark for a given peer).
>
> As you call g/send with small amounts of data, and auto partition assignment, all of your data is ending up on one partition, meaning that **the other partition's peer** continues emitting a **watermark of 0**.

---

I [found out](https://gitter.im/onyx-platform/onyx?at=5b9ee8bab4990c30eec63b64) that:

> It’s impossible to use it with the current watermark trigger, which relies on the input source. You could try to pull the previous watermark implementation [...]

In my task graph, however, **the segments** I want to aggregate in windows, are only **created in some intermediate task**, they **don't originate from the input task** as such. The input segments only provide information how to create/retrieve the content of the segments to that intermediate task.

Again, this constructs works fine in above mentioned **toy job**. The reason is that the input channel is closed at some point, which ends the job, which in turn triggers the watermark. So my toy example is actually not a good model, because it is not an open-ended stream.

If a job does get the segments in question from an actual input source, but without timestamps, Onyx seems to provide room to specify a `assign-watermark-fn`, which is an optional attribute of an *input* task. That function sets the watermark on each arrival of a new segment. In my case, this does not help, since the segments do not originate from an input task.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a work-around myself now. The [documentation](http://www.onyxplatform.org/docs/user-guide/latest/#_watermark) basically gives a clue how that can be done:

> This is a shortcut function for a punctuation trigger that fires when any piece of data has a time-based window key that is above another extent, effectively declaring that no more data for earlier windows will be arriving.

So I changed the task that emits the segments so that for every segment there will be emitted another "sentinel" like segment as well:

```
[{:id 1 :timestamp "2018-09-04 13:15:42" :msg "Hello, World!"}
{:timestamp "2018-09-03 13:15:42" :over :out}]
```

Note that the `:timestamp` is predated by the window range (here, 1 day). So it will be sent to the *previous* window. Since my data comes in chronologically, a `:punctuation` trigger can tell from the presence of a "sentinel" segment (with keyword :over) that the window can be closed. Don't forget to evict (i.e., `:trigger/post-evictor [:all]`) and throw away the "sentinel" segment from the final window. Adding `:onyx/max-peers 1` in the task map makes sure that a sentinel always arrives eventually, especially when using grouping.

Note that two assumptions go into this work-around:

1. The data comes in **chronological**
2. There are **no windows without segments**